# Angular Promises - Do Something on Both Success and Error

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a service that returns a standard resolve or reject promise.  In my controller, I currently have something like:

```
myService.myServiceFunction(id).then(function(data){
    // do something with data
    $scope.myServiceFunctionFinished = true;
}, function(data){
    // do some error handling with data
    $scope.myServiceFunctionFinished = true;
});
```

In the above, both the error and success responses will trigger `$scope.myServiceFunctionFinished` being assigned a `true` value.

Is there anyway to shorthand the above so I am not defining the same thing twice?  I am looking for the equivalent of a *finally* block if the above code was a *try catch* statement.  The variable assignment I showed above must happen after the server responds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.finally` function which will called once promise `resolve/rejected`.

**Code**

```
myService.myServiceFunction(id).then(function(data){
    //do success code
}, function(data){
    //do error code    
}).finally(function(){
    //do some final stuff which wouldn't care about promise resolve/reject
    $scope.myServiceFunctionFinished = true;
});
```

Comment: If i remember correctly the finally block can be triggered before any promises returned in the then block are resolved.  So be careful :)

Comment: @Ardesco have never seen that happen... can you provide demo that displays that behavior?

Comment: @Ardesco could you provide a example where this thing has happened with you.. I used `finally` block for cleaning up things after `promise`, never face this problem ever.

Comment: I may be remembering incorrectly, but I'm pretty sure i've seen it happen in the past.  I'll have to hunt around and see if i can find the problem.